# SAS Demographic Table

Tags: sas, tabular

I have been trying to create a demographic table like below this but I can't seem append the different tables. Please advise on where I can make adjustments in the code.

```
                Group A                           Group B          
       chort 1 cohort 2 cohort 3 subtotal cohort 4 cohort 5 cohort 6 subtotal
Age 
   n           
   mean
   sd
   median
   min
Gender
   n 
   female
   male
Race
   n 
   white 
   asian
   hispanic 
   black
```

My Code:

```
PROC FORMAT;
value content
  1=' '
  2='Age'
  3='Gender'
  4='Race'
value sex
  1='  n'
  2='  female'
  3='  male';
value race 
  1='  n'
  2='  white'
  3='  asian'
  4='  hispanic'
  5='  black';
value stat
  1='  n'
  2='  Mean'
  3='  Std. Dev.'
  4='  Median'
  5='  Minimum'; 
RUN;

DATA testtest; 
    SET test.test(keep = id group cohort age gender race); 
RUN; 

data tottest;
    set testtest;
    output;
    if prxmatch('m/COHORT 1|COHORT 2|COHORT 3/oi', cohort) then do;
        cohort='Subtotal';
        output;
    end;
    if prxmatch('m/COHORT 4|COHORT 5|COHORT 6/oi', cohort) then do;
        cohort='Subtotal';
        output;
    end;
run;

data count;
    if 0 then set testtest nobs=npats;
    call symput('npats',put(npats,1.));
    stop;
run;

proc freq data=tottest;
    tables cohort /out=patk0 noprint;
    tables cohort*sex /out=sex0 noprint;
    tables cohort*race /out=race0 noprint;
run;

PROC MEANS DATA = testtest n mean std min median; 
    class cohort; 
    VAR age; 
RUN;
```

I know that I would have to transpose it and out it in a report. But before I do that, how do I get the variable out of my proc means, proc freq, etc?

Comment: I usually write a macro to do these tables. First split your variables  into types, which variables need what type of summary, usually that's categorical vs continuous to me, but if you have ordinal or other types you need to consider that. Then I'll  build the process for each type and combine them. I have some macros at home...I'll dig them out tonight from when I reported on clinical trials, if you don't have a better answer before that.

Comment: @Reeza Thank you for your response. I'm a beginner in SAS and haven't really used a macro before. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: First, make sure you have working code for at least one variable. Then you can turn your program into a macro :). I have a short tutorial here: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/2f27939fd72d1dd7d8c8669cd39d7e67 There's an example of macro usage at the bottom of the page, you'll need to uncomment it. You would replace the macro call with your own. I don't know that this exactly meets your requirements but once you've tested feel free to modify as needed. Good Luck.

Comment: @Reeza Thanks so much for all your help. It's been incredibly helpful. QQ, if I wanted to split up the statistics by separate cohorts, like above, what kind/where would the macro be?

Comment: Personally, I split the file.So split it for one cohort, call the macro. Repeat and then merge the results. You could modify the macro as well, but I was too lazy to do that :)

Comment: That makes sense! You've been incredibly helpful. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Reeza Sorry to keep bothering you. I am still working on this demographic table. I have a problem where i.e. cohort 3 has no males. So when I merge everything becomes misaligned. Is there any way I can list out males as 0 that way I can still merge?